# Google Analytics code should be in master page or every page of asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-analytics

I need to track every single page of my website so if any one can give me idea that if i need to place Analytics tracking code in every aspx page inherited from master page or if i need to place in master page and i can track every page inherited from master page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste it in a file which is included throughtout the site maybe like header or footer files. Its a best practice to include in the footer. Reason for why you should include in all the pages so that you can checkout which pages are being visitor and etc information's.

Comment: since the header or footer files should, in theory, be in the master page, i agree

Comment: so if i put it in footer in master page then i can then track all pages visitors easily?